# How to deploy python project on a RHEL linux appliance without using PIP

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm trying to run a python project on a RHEL 7 appliance without PIP installed, nor do I have sudo access. I'm able to deploy and run my python code without issue on the appliance, just without dependencies, so I do not get very far. How do I package a python project with all dependencies so that I can avoid the need for PIP altogether?

I've looked at some examples for packaging the python projects, but they assume the box has no Internet but does have PIP installed. Being that I don't have PIP, this is not very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+without+root+access

Comment: Root access is not required. You can install `pip` without root access (`python get-pip.py --user`) and then you can either install `virtualenv` and create as many virtual environments as you need. Or install all packages as user using `pip install --user`.

Comment: I was able to download get-pip.py but using this method gets this error now: ImportError: No module named distutils.util

Comment: It seems the server has a rather dumbed down Python library. In that case you cannot install anything even without `pip`.

Comment: is there any way to "lift" up a folder with all dependencies and drop it on the appliance?

Comment: But you have to install it there so that wouldn't work. After installation they would call to stdlib modules — and some of those modules seem to be missing. You only chance is to restore Python stdlib. Perhaps the absent parts could be copied manually to `~/.local/lib/python2.7`.